# Removing specific type of Node in Pane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a pane with some Polygons, Groups and Rectangles in it, is there a proper way to remove a specific type of Node? For example I want to remove all the Polygons from the pane:

```
for (Node node: pane.getChildrenUnmodifiable()){
    if (node instanceof Polygon){
        pane.getChildren().remove(node);
    }
}
```

But this seems fishy and I don't know if it's the proper way of doing so.
Also for some reason it doesn't remove all the polygons

Answer (score 2):

You might use one of the cool new Java8 features :-)

```
pane.getChildren().removeIf(n -> n instanceof Polygon);
```